# Groovy add few conditions into findresult

Tags: groovy

```
File("path/to/file.txt").findResults{ def m = it =~ /!!(.*\.jpg)/;m ? m[0][1] : null }
```

My question is how to add next .jpeg or .bmp or .exe?

Comment: `!!(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|bmp|exe))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the other alternatives to the regexp.  E.g.

```
def data = """!!hello.txt
!!world.jpeg
!!groovy.exe
!!something.else"""

println(data.readLines().findResults{ def m = it =~ /!!(.*\.(jpe?g|exe|bmp))/;m ? m[0][1] : null })
```